# Can the proof of finding the minimum of $x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} + 3$ validly end with $x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} + 3 \geq 13$?

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, alternative-proof

I have a question where this is this expression needs to be found where it is the minimum:

$x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} + 3$ where $x > 0$

There are two options to solving this proof:

(1) Using the Arithmetic-geometric mean inequality

(2) Using the basic fact that $x^2 \geq 0$

Note: Arithmetic-Geometric mean inequality (and its manipulation):

$\sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{a+b}{2} \Rightarrow$

$2\sqrt{ab} \leq a+b$

Option (1):

Take $a = x^2$ and $b = \frac{25}{x^2}$, then:

$2\sqrt{25} \leq x^2+\frac{25}{x^2} \Rightarrow$

$10 \leq x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}$

Now, you say that the Arithmetic-geometric mean inequality is an equality when $a = b$, therefore:

$x^2 = \frac{25}{x^2} \Rightarrow$

$x = \sqrt{5}$

Now, because you know the *minimum* of the equation $10 \leq x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}$ occurs at $x = \sqrt{5}$, substituting in the minimum $x = \sqrt{5}$ into the equation $10 \leq x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}$ gives you $10$.

And with this information, you now know that the original equation $x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} + 3$ would just be an additional $+3$, therefore, the minimum of the equation would be $13$. Q.E.D.

Option (2):

Use the fact that:

$\left( x - \frac{5}{x} \right)^2  \geq 0$

now expand, and then:

$x^2 - 10 + \frac{25}{x^2} \geq 0$

$x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} \geq 10$

Now, add $3$ to both sides to get:

$x^2 + \frac{25}{x^2} +3 \geq 13$.

I was wondering whether the second option proof can actually be concluded at that. It is that proof cannot end with that because the equation might not actually reach that minimum, and because no proof is showed on which number get to that minimum, the proof will be invalid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: Concluding $f(x)\ge 13$ is not enough to say that $13$ is the minimum value of $f(x)$.

However, one can easily see that there must be *some* $x$ such that $x-5/x=0$ because this is negative when $x=1$, positive when $x=5$ and continuous between $1$ and $5$.

Then repeating the same calculation as in your argument 2, except with $=$ instead of $\ge$, shows that *that particular $x$* actually achieves $f(x)=13$.

Comment: Hi. Could you please elaborate on "_repeating the same calculation as in your arguement 2, except with $=$... actually achieves $f(x) = 13$_". Also, you say it is continuous between $1$ and $5$, but it is also negative at $2$? Thanks.

Comment: Also, why can _one easily see that there must be some $x$ such that $x-\frac{5}{x} = 0$_?

Comment: @Strikers: Because $1-\frac{5}{1}$ is negative and $5-\frac{5}{5}$ is positive and $x\mapsto x-\frac5x$ is continuous between $1$ and $5$! (That is the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)).

Comment: Okay, but I am still not sure. Also, do you find doing the calculations for the third step so I see your explanation better? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you _mind_ doing the calculations in your third sentence to clarify your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Strikers: Yes, I mind. It is you who are trying to learn something, and if you're too lazy to take the text you have already typed once, and write it down again with $=$ instead of $\ge$, then I don't see why I should waste more time typing up YOUR homework for you. Your entitled attitude doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2+\frac{25}{x^2}+3 = 5 \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{x} \right)^2+10+3.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Hi. So how would you find the minimum?

Comment: The minimum will occur when
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{x}=0
\end{eqnarray*}
so $x=\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Hi, okay so how would you know _that_?